# Private Protocol implementation?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to make an interface private and it gives me a warning, that Assigning to 
'id' from incompatible type 'test *' which is odd anyone know a work around ?

```
//test.h
@interface test : NSObject


//test.m 
@interface test() <testProtocol>

@end

@implementation

-(void) Request
{
}
@end

//protocolAndClass.h
@interface protocolAndClass : NSObject
@property (weak,nonatomic) id<testProtocol> delegate;
@end

//protocolAndClass.m

@protocol testProtocol <NSObject>
@required
-(void) Request;
@optional
@end

// Top Level Classes

test* t = [[test alloc] init]

protocolAndClass* c = [[protocolAndClass alloc] init]

protocolAndClass.delegate = t;
```

Comment: Class and Protocol names should begin with a capital letter.

Comment: If it bothers you change it, its an example and beyond the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "private protocol implementation." Implementations are typically private. But you have made the fact that `test` even conforms to `<testProtocol>` private by only declaring it in the .m. So the caller has no way to know that `test*` is of type `id<testProtocol>`, and the assignment is a mismatch. You fix this by declaring the `<testProtocol>` in the header interface, not the .m private interface, since this is something you want callers to know. You also need to declare the protocol somewhere that implementers can see it (currently it's in a .m, which makes that impossible; I don't see how the above could possibly compile).

Note: ObjC classes and protocols really need to start with capital letters. Methods really need to start with lowercase letters. This is more than just someone's personal style; ObjC relies on certain naming conventions, including capitalization, for correct behavior. So this should be something like this:

```
//Test.h
#import "ProtocolAndClass.h"
@interface Test : NSObject <TestProtocol>
@end

//Test.m
#import "Test.h"

@implementation

- (void)request
{
}
@end

//ProtocolAndClass.h

@protocol TestProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)request;
@end

@interface ProtocolAndClass : NSObject
@property (weak,nonatomic) id<TestProtocol> delegate;
@end


// Top Level Classes
#import Test.h"

Test* t = [[Test alloc] init]
ProtocolAndClass* c = [[ProtocolAndClass alloc] init]
c.delegate = t;
```

Comment: http://www.innerexception.com/2011/06/adopting-objective-c-protocol-privately.html, I can't seem to get the syntax to allow this behavior.

Comment: The technique listed is for when you are implementing a protocol that no other object needs to know you implement. That is not the case in your code. The caller must know, or else you cannot type-check the call to setDelegate:. What do you expect "private" to mean here?

Comment: This technique, BTW, is generally used for protocols like `NSURLConnectionDelegate`. Other objects do not need to know that you use `NSURLConnection` internally. In your example, "top level classes" do need to know that you implement `TestProtocol`.